# How to create an xlsx report to list all record of an entity in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have an entity Employee and i want to create a xlsx report to show a list of all employees. In that report each row would show the data of an specific employee and each column would represent an attribute. How can I create that xlsx report in odoo?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just export the data from employee? it is the same, if you dont want to export it from front end, you can make function to get the data and create xlsx file using python XlsxWriter https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/